# Creating a drawable inside class constructor (and by extending ?drawable class)

Tags: android, drawable

I am using a class that handles async loading of images. During the load, the class loads a colordrawable (that will be later assigned to downloaded image). Instead of a color, I would like to use a drawable resource to implement the "loading" image. How is this possible? Doing it "outside" this drawable class would be easier, but as a limitation I have to do it inside the class. Can't figure a way how to reference a resource inside the class.

Currently:

```
class myDrawable extends ColorDrawable {
  public myDrawable () {
     super (Color.BLACK);
  }
}
```

Is using BitmapDrawable the right way?

```
class myDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
  public myDrawable () {
     super(); // something here to fetch the drawable?
  }
}
```

BitmapDrawable constructor is as follows:

```
    public BitmapDrawable(Resources res)
```

If this can be used, how to get the right "resourcees" indentifier to be passed for it? E.g. super(R.drawable.stubImage);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static class HolderDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

    public HolderDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {
        super(mDefaultBitmap);
        bitmapDownloaderTaskReference = new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(
                bitmapDownloaderTask);

    }

    public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
        return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas arg0) {
        super.draw(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return super.getOpacity(); 
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        super.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {    
        super.setColorFilter(cf);
    }
}
```

You can create the mDefaultBitmap from downloading something online, or from a resource. That step is easy, just google it. I recommend you set mDefaultBitmap as a static field so that you don't have to create it every time you create a HolderDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the reference to `Resources`, it will be available from the `Context.getResource()`, which the context is passed as parameters in the constructor of your custom view, or your activity class itself.